# Outputting categories authors have written in as a class (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

OK, I have a very specific question that I hope someone can shed some light on.

I have a page that lists authors outputting using the following code

```
<?php

$display_admins = false;
$order_by = 'post_count'; // 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', or 'post_count'
$role = ''; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
$hide_empty = true; // hides authors with zero posts

if(!empty($display_admins)) {
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
} else {
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $exclude = array();
    foreach($admins as $ad) {
        $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
    }
    $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
    $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role.'&order='.'DESC');
}
$authors = array();
foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
    $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
    if(!empty($hide_empty)) {
        $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
        if($numposts < 1) continue;
    }
    $authors[] = (array) $user;
}

echo '<ul class="contributors">';
foreach($authors as $author) {
    $display_name = $author['data']->display_name;
    $avatar = get_wp_user_avatar($author['ID'], 'medium');
    $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);
    $filter = get_userdata($author['ID'])->yim;

    echo '<li><div class="home ', $filter,'  "><div class="feature-image"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '">', $avatar , '</a></div>
    <div class="post-title"><a href="', $author_profile_url, '"><h3>', $display_name, '</h3></a></div>
    </div>
    </li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

(I got this from another support topic and tweaked it, although I can't remember where)

At the moment, the $filter variable is just a string I enter in the 'Yahoo IM' profile box (a dirty fix to test the filter). I'd like this to actually be a list of the categories (as  slugs that I will output in to the class="" part of the loop) that the author has posted in.

I essentially want to be able to filter the authors by category that they have posted in, and the filter I'm using (Isotope) operates using the class, so outputting the categories in to the class of the markup is what I'm after.

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Hmm, might be a bit hacky...but you could use a `wp_query` to get posts from the `author ID`, then a foreach to stick the categories in an array. Seems a bit long winded though! Will have a think of another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Returns the posts made by the author
$authorPosts = get_posts("author={$author['ID']}"); 

$categoryList = array(); // reset previous values
foreach ($authorPosts as $post) {
  $postCategories = get_the_category($post->ID);

  // Add to the categories the author has posted in
  foreach ($postCategories as $category)
    $categoryList[] = $category->slug;
} 

// Removes duplicate categories
$categoryList = array_unique($categoryList);
```

You can then use `$filter = implode(' ', $categoryList);` and add it to your html.

Comment: That makes complete sense, but I fear I'm doing something wrong as that is just outputting the word 'Array' in to the html.

I assume this code goes just before I echo the contributors list? And then I can just call $categoryList inside the markup?

Please excuse my brainfreeze today

Comment: You're right. This has to run inside the authors loop to get access to the authorId. `$categoryList` is an array of the categories. You can use `implode(' ', $categoryList)` to get a plain text version. Eg. `"category1 category2 category3"`

Comment: Just noticed something - the category list appears to compound with each author. So for author one you have 'category-1 category-2' then for author two it shows 'category-1 category-2 category-3' even if author two has only posted in category-3. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to reset `$categoryList` after each loop. I added `$categoryList = array()` to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

RE not storing the array from the other answer, you can just echo out the slugs there and then like this:

```
$authorPosts = get_posts("author={$author['ID']}"); 

foreach ($authorPosts as $post) {
    $postCategories = get_the_category($post->ID);

    // Add to the categories the author has posted in
    foreach ($postCategories as $category)
        echo($category->slug);
    }
```

otherwise if you want to put your PHP at the top and echo out the slugs further down the page pop there where ever you want to echo them:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($categoryList as $category) {

    echo($categoryList[$i]);
    $i++;

}
```